# MongoDB having a syntax error

Tags: arrays, mongodb, collections

E QUERY    [main] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):5:77

```
db.users.insert
([{"username":"jruiz"},
{"password":"123456"},
{"email":"jessica_ruiz04@hotmail.com"},
{"users_answers":[{"question": ObjectId("58c38d076677dcee6ed2dba7"),"Alright","postdate": new Date()},
{"question": ObjectId("58c38d8c6677dcee6ed2dba8"),"To find healhty coping skills", "postdate": new Date()},
{"question": ObjectId("58c38da86677dcee6ed2dba9"),"Stress", "cat" :ObjectId("58c38bab610a0365ea9775bd"),"postdate":new Date()},
{"question": ObjectId("58c38ded6677dcee6ed2dbaa"),"3-5 hours","postdate": new Date()},
{"question": ObjectId("58c38e006677dcee6ed2dbab"),"Yes, I have done DBT","level": ObjectId("58c38f8f6677dcee6ed2dbae"),"postdate": new Date()}]},
{"goals_checklist":[{"label":"mindfull skills","status":"completed"}, {"label": ObjectId("58c390cf6677dcee6ed2dbbf"), "status":"incomplete"}]}])
```

Comment: users_answers array is not a valid json document, mongodb can store only key value pairs of documents, ex, users_anwers:[ {key:val,key: val} ,{}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are missing key for one field, that's why it is giving error.

`db.users.insert([{"username":"jruiz"},{"password":"123456"},{"email":"jessica_ruiz04@hotmail.com"},{"users_answers":[{"question":ObjectId("58c38d076677dcee6ed2dba7"),"missingkey":"Alright","postdate": new Date()},{"question": ObjectId("58c38d8c6677dcee6ed2dba8"),"missingkey":"To find healhty coping skills", "postdate": new Date()},{"question": ObjectId("58c38da86677dcee6ed2dba9"),"missingkey":"Stress", "cat" :ObjectId("58c38bab610a0365ea9775bd"),"postdate":new Date()},{"question": ObjectId("58c38ded6677dcee6ed2dbaa"),"missingkey":"3-5 hours","postdate": new Date()},{"question": ObjectId("58c38e006677dcee6ed2dbab"),"missingkey":"Yes, I have done DBT","level": ObjectId("58c38f8f6677dcee6ed2dbae"),"postdate": new Date()}]},{"goals_checklist":[{"label":"mindfull skills","status":"completed"}, {"label": ObjectId("58c390cf6677dcee6ed2dbbf"), "status":"incomplete"}]}])`

Here I have added `missingkey`. This will run, but still your structure is wrong, it will create 5 records with `username`,`password` etc field-name.

I have formatted your code :

`db.users.insert([{"username":"jruiz","password":"123456","email":"jessica_ruiz04@hotmail.com","users_answers":[{"question":ObjectId("58c38d076677dcee6ed2dba7"),"missingkey":"Alright","postdate":new Date()},{"question":ObjectId("58c38d8c6677dcee6ed2dba8"),"missingkey":"To find healhty coping skills","postdate":new Date()},{"question":ObjectId("58c38da86677dcee6ed2dba9"),"missingkey":"Stress","cat":ObjectId("58c38bab610a0365ea9775bd"),"postdate":new Date()},{"question":ObjectId("58c38ded6677dcee6ed2dbaa"),"missingkey":"3-5 hours","postdate":new Date()},{"question":ObjectId("58c38e006677dcee6ed2dbab"),"missingkey":"Yes, I have done DBT","level":ObjectId("58c38f8f6677dcee6ed2dbae"),"postdate":new Date()}],"goals_checklist":[{"label":"mindfull skills","status":"completed"},{"label":ObjectId("58c390cf6677dcee6ed2dbbf"),"status":"incomplete"}]}])`

It will create proper record of user.